# Query many-to-many in OData

Tags: join, odata

There's a database that I have no control over (so cannot simply create a view) that has its tables exposed by OData.  Logically, the tables look something like.

```
create table one
(
  one_id int not null,
  constraint pk_one primary key (one_id)
)

create table two
(
  two_id int not null,
  one_id int not null,
  constraint pk_two primary key (two_id, one_id),
  foreign key (one_id) references one (one_id)
)

create table three
(
  three_id int not null,
  one_id int not null,
  name varchar(50),
  constraint pk_three primary key (three_id, one_id),
  foreign key (one_id) references one (one_id)
)
```

My problem is how to write an OData URL such that, given a value for **two.two_id**, I can retrieve all rows from table **three** that would be associated via table **one**.  In SQL, this would be something like:

```
select three_id, name 
from one join two on one.one_id = two.one_id
    join three on one.one_id = three.one_id
where two.two_id = 2
```

I'm unable to figure out how to do the navigation in a single request in OData.

Answer (score 0):

From table one you can expand to table two and table three, filter on two_id and select data from three.

e.g.

> /one?$expand=two,three&$filter=two/two_id eq
>   2&$select=three/three_id,three/name

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not able to get that to work.  Of course, the tables above were artificial to make things easier to read but, using the real table names substituted in, I can get a result without the filter.  However, I get a 400 error the minute I add the "filter" portion of the URL.  Here's what I've tried ( assuming that one=edel_component, two=edel_prod_xref_comp, three=edel_component_files): /edel_component?$expand=edel_prod_xref_comp,edel_component_files&$filter=edel_prod_xref_comp/tops_code%20eq%20%27SEVEN.00200%27

Comment: Are there any further error details? Also is the field tops_code a string data type in the entity/table?

Comment: Yes, it is a string...unfortunately they keyed their table that way.  Switching from IE to Firefox, there is some further information: The 'tops_code' is not allowed at position 20. Member access or specifying a type identifier on a resource set reference is not allowed.